# Looping JSON data through multiple divs of the same class

Tags: jquery, html, json

I'm trying to populate a column of DIVS of the same class with JSON data. But instead, what I get is just one DIV with the last JSON record. And I need all them DIVs to have JSON data ascending. First DIV - First record, second DIV - second record and so on.

This is my HTML

```
<div class="main"></div>
<div class="main"></div>
<div class="main"></div>
```

And this is my JS with JSON

```
var json = {"items": [
{
  "title": "sample 1",
  "author": "author 1"
},
{
  "title": "sample 2",
  "author": "author 2"
},
{
  "title": "sample 3",
  "author": "author 3"
}  
]};

var main-div = document.getElementsByClassName("main")[0];
var items = json.items;
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {    
    main-div.innerHTML = items[i].title;   
}
```

Obviously, I'm doing something wrong here. I was thinking about looping through
`main-div.innerHTML = items[i].title;`, but have no slightest idea how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the first div populates fine and If you have the exact number of divs as json items, you can simply do the following:

```
var main_div = document.getElementsByClassName("main");
var items = json.items;
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {    
    main_div[i].innerHTML = items[i].title;   
}
```

Here's a similar example : http://jsfiddle.net/5e4phkzg/

Comment: You do realize main-div is not a valid identifier?

Comment: Yup. Fixed it via underscore.

Comment: So dumb of me. That worked! Thanks! Also, I've changed the number of divs to smaller and then to bigger than number of json items and it worked out as expected ie. if there were too many divs, it populated only those that had matching items.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

- main-div is not a valid identifier, change it to mainDiv.
- `var main-div = document.getElementsByClassName("main")[0];` is getting just the first element, drop the [0] and you can use `mainDiv[i] in your loop